# Convert EBNF to BNF

Tags: bnf, ebnf

I am struggling to convert this EBNF to BNF. Using the image:

[image]

I converted this to EBNF and would like to now convert this to BNF.

The EBNF I have two alternatives:

```
 number_constant ::= ( | "-")  digit+  ("." digit+ |  )

 number_constant ::= "-"? digit+ ("." digit+)?
```

The part where I am struggling is  the middle of the diagram, I have digit defined as 1-9 so can't use digit as keyword. I was thinking of breaking down the diagram such as the first part:

```
<min> ::= '   ' | "-"
```

Then for the mid part:

```
<dig> ::= <digit> | <digit> <dig>
```

Combined this would look simply like:

```
<number_constant> ::= <min> <dig> <last_part>
```

Then I am unsure of the last part.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your `dig` solution seems correct.

The last part can be implemented with:

```
<last_part> ::= "." <dig> | ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Extended BNF sure lets you have things a lot more concise.

Here's a variation based on the semantics of what goes into making up a decimal number:

```
<number_constant> ::= <integer> 
                      | <integer> '.' <whole_number>

<integer> ::= <integer>
              | '- <whole_number>

<whole_number> ::= Digit 
                   | <whole_number> Digit
```

[image]